# Why sendmail sending blank text file?

Tags: sendmail

I want to create a script which able to send the log file by email. The problem now is the text file I have received through email is blank. Which part is the problem?

```
MYSQL_SLOW_LOG_USER="****"
MYSQL_SLOW_LOG_PASSWORD="*****"

SLOW_LOG="/var/log/mysql-slow.log"

cat <<EOF | mysql -u $MYSQL_SLOW_LOG_USER -p$MYSQL_SLOW_LOG_PASSWORD
SET GLOBAL log_queries_not_using_indexes = 'OFF';
SET GLOBAL slow_query_log = 'OFF';
FLUSH SLOW LOGS;
EOF

cat $SLOW_LOG > /tmp/corpsoDB.txt

recipient="cronjobauto@yahoo.com"

(
cat - <<END
Subject: MySQL Slow Query Log Report-Corpso
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-omgemailslikewhoa"

GET ON IT.

---omgemailslikewhoa
Content-Type: text/plain; name="corpsoDB.txt"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="corpsoDB.txt"
END

cat /tmp/corpsoDB.txt

cat <<END
---omgemailslikewhoa--

END
) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -i -- $recipient
```

/tmp/corpsoDB.txt

```
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.7.31-log (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started w$
Tcp port: 0  Unix socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
```

tee /tmp/sendmail-input.txt

```
Subject: MySQL Slow Query Log Report-Corpso
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="-omgemailslikewhoa"

---omgemailslikewhoa
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Disposition: inline

GET ON IT.

---omgemailslikewhoa
Content-Type: text/plain; name="corpsoDB.txt"
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="corpsoDB.txt"
/usr/sbin/mysqld, Version: 5.7.31-log (MySQL Community Server (GPL)). started w$
Tcp port: 0  Unix socket: /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
Time                 Id Command    Argument
---omgemailslikewhoa--
```

This is what I have only received from the email
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jnNuezyWxYAdNW_ZZ9ZvG1MG3ZJFLaBc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You'd almost certainly be better off using `mpack` (pack a file in MIME format) rather than rolling your own MIME-handling code

Answer (score 1):

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="corpsoDB.txt"
END

cat /tmp/corpsoDB.txt
```

You should be generating a newline between the bodypart headers and the bodypart content.

Comment: sorry, I am new to this. How to generate newline between the bodypart headers and the bodypart content?

Comment: The same way that you did between the message headers and body only 5 lines before that.